# How do I get the code to count how many times specific words occur?

Tags: python, grok

This is from the grok learning website for favorite dessert.  I am not sure how to get it to add how many of the votes occured.

```
votes = {}
msg = input("Name:vote ")
while msg:
  name, vote = msg.split(":")
  if vote not in votes:
    votes[vote] = [name]
  else:
    votes[vote].append(name)
  msg = input("Name:vote ")
for vote in votes:
  print(vote, vote.count(votes), "vote(s):", ' '.join(votes[vote]))
```

This is the expected outcome:

```
Name:vote Greg:chocolate
Name:vote Teena:macaroons
Name:vote Georgina:apple pie
Name:vote Will:chocolate
Name:vote Sophia:gelato
Name:vote Sam:ice cream
Name:vote James:chocolate
Name:vote Kirsten:gelato
Name:vote 
apple pie 1 vote(s): Georgina
gelato 2 vote(s): Sophia Kirsten
chocolate 3 vote(s): Greg Will James
macaroons 1 vote(s): Teena
ice cream 1 vote(s): Sam
```

Comment: at start set `count_votes = 0` and inside `while` loop you can do `count_votes += 1`

Comment: or at start set `count_votes = 0` and inside `for` loop use `count_votes += vote.count(votes)`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try printing the length of each list.

```
votes = {}
msg = input("Name:vote ")
while msg:
  name, vote = msg.split(":")
  if vote not in votes:
    votes[vote] = [name]
  else:
    votes[vote].append(name)
  msg = input("Name:vote ")
for vote in votes:
  print(vote, len(votes[vote]), "vote(s):", ' '.join(votes[vote]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vote.count(votes)` is giving you the trouble. You can use `len()` for that.

More importantly, I think your code would be easier to understand if you use both key and value in your loop:

```
for food, voters in votes.items(): 
  print(food, len(voters), 'vote(s): ', ' '.join(voters))
```